# Python, Removing New Line in List

Tags: python, list, format, newline

I have the following Codesample:

**Codesample:**

```
import string
import fileinput
Path = '/Volumes/test_copy.txt'

#/I
filename = Path
with open(filename) as file_object:
     lines = file_object.readlines()

mylists = [item + "ENDTOKEN" + for item in lines]
mylists2 = ["STARTTOKEN" + item + "ENDTOKEN" + for item in lines] 

#/O
print(mylists)
print(mylists2)
```

**Content of test_copy.txt:**

```
textprompt     nextelement
```

**Output:**

```
textprompt     nextelement
ENDTOKEN

STARTTOKENtextprompt     nextelement
ENDTOKEN
```

**Preferred Output**:

```
STARTTOKENtextprompt     nextelementENDTOKEN # 1. Pref.
STARTTOKENtextprompt     nextelement ENDTOKEN # 2. Pref.
```

So far the newline only occurs in the after '+'
So the Python mechanism of newlines.

Is there anyway to change the list properties?
I'm also aware of the same issue for print(), but i know how to fix it there with more '''.

**Edit:**
However, I'd like to have the lists cleaner.
Printing out list[0] does print it also with \n

I have also tryed conditions, behind the comprehension with "\n" or " ".

Changed 'list' to ‘mylists‘. Thx to rockzxm & BeRT2me
here.

> Solved by BeRT2me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name. You're overwriting the built in `list` functionality by doing so.

Comment: What does your *input* look like, aka, what are the contents of `test_copy.txt`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I have changed the list to mylists.

Comment: So, your input file is a single line?

Comment: Actually multiples lines at the same issue.
It was a list of Hotkeys in VSC and the corresponding function in the same format. 
My goal was more to insert html <table> </table> <tr> </tr> f.e. etc. to the Start Token and END Token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test.txt`

```
textprompt   otherstuff
nexttextprompt  morestuffs
```

Doing:

```
with open('deleteme.txt') as f:
    # Either of these methods eliminate the new lines at the end.
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    # OR
    # lines = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in f.readlines()]

output = ["STARTTOKEN" + item + "ENDTOKEN" for item in lines]

# We can print like you want like so:
print(*output, sep='\n')

# But it seems like maybe you actually want a string:
output = '\n'.join(output)
print(output)
```

Output (The same both times):

```
STARTTOKENtextprompt   otherstuffENDTOKEN
STARTTOKENnexttextprompt  morestuffsENDTOKEN
```

Comment: Oh perfect. This works great!
Also the * as the argument in print is helpful.
Thank you for your time.